# Find Associativity of this Cache?

Tags: algorithm, caching

Given a Cache with the following characteristics:

```
Main Memory: 16 bit Address
Cache Size: 256 Bytes
Cache Block Size: 8 Bytes
Cache Tag Size: 11 bits
```

What is the associativity of this Cache? Is it n-way Associative? If so what is n? Can someone please explain this so I can understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [nice illustration](http://csillustrated.berkeley.edu/PDFs/handouts/cache-3-associativity-handout.pdf).

Here is how it works: Your address size is 16 bits, so you have 16 bits for the tag plus the index plus the offset within a cache block. If we assume that we want to address single bytes in the cache (which is usually the case), we need 3 bits to address 1 byte within a block (since each cache block is 8 = 2^3 bytes). That leaves 16 - 3 - 11 = 2 bytes for the index. With two bytes, we can address 2^2 = 4 different sets. We have 256 / 8 = 32 blocks in the cache (size of the cache / size of one block). Those 32 blocks are split into 4 sets, so each set holds 8 cache blocks. Your cache is thus 8-way associative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Just to verify I am correct, is n = 4?

Comment: How did you get n = 4? You can edit your question and add your current solution, so we can check.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer you really made my day! If the goal was to address 4 byte words instead of single bytes?

Comment: Well you'd need 1 byte to address a word within a block, so you have 16 - 11 - 1 = 4 bytes for the index, which means you could address 16 sets, so each set holds 2 blocks, so n = 2.

Comment: This seems like a homework exercise, so please make sure to check all the assumptions I made with your text book or slides - your teachers might make assumptions that are different from mine.

Comment: Well, Thanks a lot! Seems pretty fine to me... Do you have any assumption you are not sure about?

Comment: I am actually very grateful for your help! Have a nice day!

Comment: Sure thing, mate. The one assumption that stands out is about addressing single bytes in a block. But since you asked about addressing words in a block, it should be ok. Another assumption is that tag + index + offset in block = 16 bit.

Comment: Seems OK, Thanks a lot! :D